# Ajax + PHP salvando campos vazios no banco

Tags: php, ajax

Quando utilizo somente html e php (action) os dados são inseridos com sucesso no banco, porém quando utilizo o ajax os dados são salvos com os campos vazios (inclusive os campos NOT NULL no banco).
Poderiam me ajudar a encontrar o erro?
Versão do jquery: 3.5.1

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" id="cad-form" action="">
              <div class="form-group cad-container">
                <label>Qual o nome completo?</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder="Nome e sobrenome">
                <label>E a data de nascimento?</label>
                <input inputmode="numeric" name="data-nasc" class="form-control um" id="cad-dat-nasc" placeholder="Ex: 01/01/2020">
                <label>Qual o telefone? </label>
                <input inputmode="numeric" name="telefone" class="form-control um" id="cad-tel"placeholder="Ex: (99) 9 9999-9999">
                <label>Onde mora? </label>
                <input class="form-control" name="endereco" placeholder="Rua, numero, bairro e cidade">
                <label>Qual o CPF?</label>
                <input inputmode="numeric" name="cpf" class="form-control um" id="cad-cpf" placeholder="Ex: 999.999.999-99">
                <label>E o RG?</label>
                <input inputmode="numeric" name="rg" class="form-control um" id="cad-rg"placeholder="Ex: 99.999999-9">
              </div>
              <!--o cad-btn deve estar dentro do formulario-->
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="volta-btn">Voltar</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="cad-btn">Cadastrar</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cad-form').submit(function(){
    var dados = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "cadastro.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {dados},
      success: function(data){
         console.log(data);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Não foi possível cadastrar, contate o suporte ténico! :(");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  $nome = $_POST['nome'];
  $dataNasc = $_POST['data-nasc'];
  $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
  $endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
  $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
  $rg = $_POST['rg'];

  if (empty($nome)) {
    $banco = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'luanaconsolini');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cliente VALUES ('', '$nome', '$dataNasc', '$telefone', '$endereco', '$cpf', '$rg')";
    mysqli_query($banco, $sql);
    echo "Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!";

    echo "Nome: ".$nome;
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Está com erro de sintaxe no `data:{dados}` não tem essas chaves.

Comment: Eu havia modificado essa parte um pouco depois de postar, mas nao adiantou

Comment: o primeiro problema é que  EMPTY  confere se a variável está vazia e retornará true quando uma variável for vazia. Quando você envia o formulário obviamente a variável $nome não estará vazia portanto não entrará no if (empty($nome)) {. Para fazer entrar no if negue o EMPTY colocando uma interjeição antes, if (!empty($nome)) { ou seja se a variavel Não estiver vazia.

Answer (score 1):

O que está acontecendo é que a requisição Ajax está sendo cancelada ao enviar o formulário. O seu código envia o via Ajax e via formulário ao mesmo tempo, o envio pelo formulário faz com que o browser navegue para o `action`. Para enviar somente via Ajax, você precisa cancelar o envio padrão do formulário:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cad-form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Passe o parametro data dentro do Ajax sem as chaves.

A função serialize() já envia os dados no formato necessário.

Caso não utilize o serialize() aí vc passa os dados entre chaves no formato JSON

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cad-form').submit(function(){
    var dados = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "cadastro.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: dados, //Remova as chaves
      success: function(data){
         console.log(data);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Não foi possível cadastrar, contate o suporte ténico! :(");
      }
    });

    return false; //Adicione o RETURN FALSE para que seu form não seja enviado sem o AJAX. Desabilitando a função padrão do form que é fazer o request na pagina
  });
});
```